# Creating edittext with (yes/no) in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

i have a contex menu, where i can choose to EDIT or ADD an element on my ListView. I decided to solve it by adding EditText in fragment. i have this code:

```
  private void addItem(int position) {
        /*

        */
        monthAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }*
```

How to create EditText with asking if user want to refuse and get string from it?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void addItem(int position) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Введите Вашу новую вещь");

        // alert.setMessage("Message");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);

        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String qq = input.getText().toString();
                myArr.add(qq);
                monthAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            }
        });
        alert.show();


    }
```